# Cordova-Like Hybrid App Framework - But Offline

Tags: cordova, mobile, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I've been looking into creating a mobile app (for both iOS and Android) out of my responsive website.

I understand that the open-source project that enables you to do that is [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), and the most popular SaaS version of it is [Adobe PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/).

After taking a look at PhoneGap and [some of its competitors](http://sixrevisions.com/mobile/cross-platform-mobile-apps/), I understand that [they all work in the same way](http://phonegap.com/2012/05/02/phonegap-explained-visually/):

1. Developer builds responsive website.
2. Developer uses one of the SasS options/vanilla Cordova in order to wrap said website in an iOS/Android package (optionally using [some of the framework's native SDKs](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins), to help the "app" get native-like functionalities.).
3. Developer uploads packaged "app" to various app stores.

If I'm not mistaken, this means that **all Cordova and its derivatives do**  (no disrespect intended, obviously) is **take a URL, allow the code in it to use some native functions, and wrap it in a package suitable for mobile phones**.

My site is different - I don't really care about internet connection.

All I want is for my HTML & CSS to work on phones that are located in remote places with very bad internet connection.

So - loading the website in a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is not enough for me, I want it to **Run Without Internet Connection To Load The Initial URL.**

Is there a service/open-source project that caters to my specific need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have installed node, npm, and cordova.
command to create a project with cordova 
    `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

When you create a project with cordova you have www directory in your apps rootDir here you can put your html, css and js code directly.
if you build your app with cordova your app will not fetch these web pages from web. 
Further if you want some data to be fetched from Web you can use Web-Services using angular js or using java-script

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have a reference as to which web services enables me to work with the web?

Comment: It's easy, You can refer [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) url. Example code: `function Hello($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting').
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.greeting = data;
        });
}` you can connect to any web service using angular.js's http module or you can use plain java-script to connect to web-service.